# Framework.net service, using ConfidentialClientApplication and the Outlook Tasks REST API, got StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi, bearer-token

## Hello World !

Hello to everyone !
I'm new to StackOverflow, so I'll do my best to explain my problem better.

### The Issue

I'm tring to interact with Outlook Calendar and Tasks REST API from a c# .net framework cli program, that will became a background Windows service.

I have created a dedicated Outlook account,
registered the app on the [Azure portal](https://aad.portal.azure.com) and adapted the [rest-sender](https://github.com/jasonjoh/rest-sender) project.

With `PublicClientApplicationBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive` I can get a valid, even though effimeral (1 hour), access token and listing my tasks.
It works for other API calls too,
but the problem is that every time I require a token it shows and *interactive* web browser window for picking up an account.
The app will became a Windows background service in a Production Headless Server, so no interactive window is possible.

I discovered `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient` that needs a client secret.
I have created one from the Azure portal.
I can get a token, but It seems that it isn't authorized.

### The Portal

[the app](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/OutlookTestMainPage.png)
This is a screen of the app in the Azure's page.

[auth](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/OutlookTest_Auth.png)
These are the authentications settings.

[auths](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/OutlookTest_Auths.png)
These are the authorizations settings.

[secret](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/OutlookTest_Secret.png)
This is the secret page.

[mail](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/AccountPerm.png)
From the mail I can see these permission (granted with the `GetInteractiveToken`)

[token](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/jwt.png)
This is the decoded token.

---

This is an illustrative code:

```cs
static async Task<string> GetSecretAccessToken()
{
    var client =
        ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<applicationId>")
            .WithClientSecret("<clientSecret>")
            .Build();

    var result = client.AcquireTokenForClient(new []{
        "https://outlook.office.com/.default",
    }).ExecuteAsync();

    var r = result.Result.AccessToken;
    return r;
}

static async Task<string> GetInteractiveAccessToken()
{
    var client =
        PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<applicationId>")
            .Build();

    var result = client.AcquireTokenInteractive(new []{
        "https://outlook.office.com/Tasks.ReadWrite"
    }).ExecuteAsync();

    var r = result.Result.AccessToken;
    return r;
}

static async Task<string> GetAccessFromPasswordToken(string[] scopes){
            try
            {
                var b =
                    PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("applicationId"))
                        .Build();
                var result = b.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "CodeGen.Preventizzatore@Outlook.it", GetSecureString()).ExecuteAsync();
                return result.Result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Output.WriteLine(Output.Error, "Could not acquire access token: Error code: {0}, Error message: ",
                    ex.ErrorCode, ex.Message);
                return string.Empty;
            }
}

static async Task ListTasks()
{
    string token = await GetAccessToken();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
        new HttpMethod("GET"),
        new UriBuilder("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/CodeGen.Preventizzatore@Outlook.it/taskfolders").Uri
    );
    request.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    request.Headers.UserAgent.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue("rest-sender", "1.0"));
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var result = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        return; // when GetSecretAccessToken
    // when GetInteractiveAccessToken
    string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And this is the manifest on Azure:

```
{
    "id": "a752666c-11a9-425e-a382-c63ebcbc8bb2",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "608bd039-6bc9-4a7e-ad86-2b6a3e20584b",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2019-06-21T08:18:56Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://608bd039-6bc9-4a7e-ad86-2b6a3e20584b"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "CodeGen.Preventizzatore",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "c4a2fe3a-a09c-41ff-9115-40a2a2ef1a89",
            "startDate": "2019-06-21T11:46:06.306Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2019-06-21T11:46:08.2116173Z",
            "hint": "nR?",
            "displayName": "Preventizzatore"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": null,
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "bbd1ca91-75e0-4814-ad94-9c5dbbae3415",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6b49b74d-642f-4417-a6b4-820576845707",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "bf24470f-10c1-436d-8d53-7b997eb473be",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "77e65b5a-ceae-48b3-9490-50a86a038a48",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "dc890d15-9560-4a4c-9b7f-a736ec74ec40",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "798ee544-9d2d-430c-a058-570e29e34338",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "c1b0de0a-1de9-455d-919f-eca451053141",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2c6a42ca-0d4d-49ad-bc0e-21222c449a65",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ef54d2bf-783f-4e0f-bca1-3210c0444d99",
                    "type": "Role"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2dfdc6dc-2fa7-4a2c-a922-dbd4f85d17be",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

---

When using the non-interactive token I get:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: private
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token"
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
  request-id: 8a2ccebc-e8c3-4ec2-b8cb-64d1005a5bf7
  X-CalculatedBETarget: MR2P264MB0817.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
  X-BackEndHttpStatus: 401
  X-RUM-Validated: 1
  x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;reason="The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.";error_category="invalid_grant"
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-BeSku: WCS5
  X-DiagInfo: MR2P264MB0817
  X-BEServer: MR2P264MB0817
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-FEServer: MRXP264CA0011
  X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 25DDA6AB2E72497199D611B555DACB60 Ref B: MIL30EDGE0414 Ref C: 2019-06-24T06:10:44Z
  Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 06:10:43 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

Both `GetSecretAccessToken` and `GetInteractiveAccessToken` provide a token, but only the interactive one works in the `ListTasks` method.
I need the other one for working with Win service.

I read that `https://outlook.office.com/.default` make the app use the static app permissions, which I set on the Azure portal.
But I can't get this method working.

I just don't know what kind of authorization it needs to work in this mode.

It's almost a week that I'm tring to make this working, without success.
Maybe I'm missing something trivial...
So I seek help on the best place on the planet.

I also found an example in .net core that register a device code, but I'll prefere to stay with base .net framework, because I already have a running project on my customer system.

I hope I have clarified my issue and that is feasible.
It would be very nice to have an Outlook integration.

*Thanks* in advance.

==============

### Tl;Dr;

The Microsoft identity platform doesn't support personal accounts, so if you want to access outlook365.com REST API from a background service/daemon you'll need to be under Azure AD and to be approved by an admin (He'll press the "Grant admin consent for [yourself]" Button).
Otherwise you won't be able to perform any request, because your non-interactive token won't contain any scope permission.

Thanks Jason Johnston for the big help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the client credentials flow to get an application token. This token has no user context to it, so you cannot use the `/me` segment in your request URL. Replace that with `/users/{user-id}`. `{user-id}` is either the user's object ID (obtained by doing a `GET /users` call), or their UPN (typically their email address).

I would also recommend copying the token and parsing it at https://jwt.ms. You want to look in the token and make sure it contains the `Tasks.Read` permission.

Also make sure that you've obtained admin consent for the application permissions you've configured on your app registration. If you are the administrator, you should see a **Grant consent** section just under the **API permissions** section with a button you can click to grant consent.

[image]

### Personal accounts

If you're writing this to access a personal Outlook.com account, you cannot use client credentials flow. That particular flow is only available to work or school accounts on Office 365.

Azure OAuth currently does not support non-interactive flows for personal accounts. The closest you could get is to implement [token cache serialization](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization), then do an interactive login with the app once (to seed the cache with the user's refresh token). Then on subsequent runs you could call `AcquireTokenSilent`.

Comment: Good day @JasonJohMSFT 
Thank you for your help !
Btw, congratulation : you have done a great work with the repositories !

I had a suspect with the /me part, unfortunately it's the same story with the /user/UPN.
I had decoded the [token](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/jwt.png), but
I can't find any permission, but it shows the applicationId.

Using the 'https://outlook.office.com/.default' How/Where can I grant permission to it ?

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. You need to provide admin consent to the application permissions. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I 've updated the images, because I didn't realized that I was displaying the info of another app (OutlookTest was registered on my Account, while this one is registered to the dedicated account).
Sorry for the confusion.

I conduct other experiments, but I still get 'Unauthorized' responses.

Comment: Intresting: it's [strange](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Denis-net/OutlookTest/master/strange.png) that I can't see the grant button.
How can I make it visible ?

Comment: You have to be an administrator for your tenant. I'm guessing that you're not :). If not, you'll need to get an administrator to login to the portal and click that button.

Comment: What administrator you 're talking about ?
Nope I'm not.
I just created a new personal account and signed in with it.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately you cannot use app permissions with a personal account. Sorry I missed that part of your problem description.

Comment: A quick question: are you writing this to access tasks in your Outlook.com account, or will this be accessing data in an Office 365 organization?

Comment: I just want to update my dedicated Outlook.com account's tasks and events not for organizations.

Comment: Ok, editing answer once more to give an option for personal accounts.

Comment: I updated the code, I tried it but I got : 
MsalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).

Comment: What about : `PublicClientApplication.PublicAcquireTokenWithDeviceCode` and `PublicClientApplication`.`AcquireTokenSilent`... are them available without an admin ?

I prefere the `PublicClientApplication`.`AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword`, though

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :|. Azure doesn't support the password flow with personal accounts either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. Device Code is still interactive (you have to open a browser to authenticate then get a code to enter in your app). AcquireTokenSilent requires a token cache. You'd need to implement some sort of storage for the cache and interactively login at least once. That's probably the only option at this point.

Comment: Unfortuately also the device flow is under Azure AD tenat:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code

I ended the options 
What was it like before Azure AD was invented ?
Was impossible to access an Account data at time ?

Do you know where I could propose a feature request ?

Comment: Nevermind,

Anyway Thank you Jason for the great help !
I have all the information I need.
Have a nice day !